# Custom User Control In Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, shopping-cart

I have a Custom User Control in the page. In this  Custom User Control there are labels, DELETE ITEM Button and Quantity Textbox.
In my page there is a ListBox which gets items from list, list is generated from local storage.

Now When I click on DELETE ITEM Button, It Goes to ListBox_SelectionChanged and takes the Selectedindex and further goes to DeleteButton_Tap and provides Selectedindex to it and deletes the item.

Now the problem is, if i click inside Quantity Textbox, it does not first goto ListBox_SelectionChanged to get SelectedIndex of item you want to update the quantity. but it directly goes to QuantityBox_TextChanged inside Custom User Control.

How can i send the SelectedIndex of the item of which i am trying to change the quantity?

EDIT-----------------------------CODE of Custom Control//

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace XMLParsing
{
    public partial class CustomCartFavControl : UserControl
    {
        public CustomCartFavControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Singleton singletonInstance = Singleton.mft;


        private const string strConnectionString = @"isostore:/MFTDB9.sdf";


        private void deleteItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {


            //Confirm:
            MessageBoxResult resultDelete = MessageBox.Show("Delete This Item From Cart?", "Cart:", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (resultDelete == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                using (MFTDataContext MFTdb = new MFTDataContext(strConnectionString))
                {
                    IQueryable<Database> ListQuery = from Item in MFTdb.MFTCart where Item.ProductUniqueID == singletonInstance.CartItemIDs[singletonInstance.ItemToChange] select Item;
                    Database itemRemove = ListQuery.FirstOrDefault();
                    MFTdb.MFTCart.DeleteOnSubmit(itemRemove);
                    MFTdb.SubmitChanges();

                }
                singletonInstance.somethingDeletedFromCart = true;

            }
            else if (resultDelete == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                singletonInstance.somethingDeletedFromCart = false;



            }


           //END 
        }



        private void QuantityBoxLabel_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (QuantityBoxLabel.Text != "")
            {
                singletonInstance.QuantityChanged = int.Parse(QuantityBoxLabel.Text);
            }

        }

        private void QuantityBoxLabel_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           //Update Cart
            if (singletonInstance.QuantityOriginal == singletonInstance.QuantityChanged)
            {
            //Do Nothing! Quantity Not Changed
                singletonInstance.SomethingChanged = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Work here for Quantity Update etc code:
                singletonInstance.SomethingChanged = true;
                //((Cart)this.Page).UpdateCartMethod();
                if (singletonInstance.QuantityChanged == 0)
                {
                    // new quantity =0
                    MessageBox.Show("You Didn't Enter A Valid Quantity. Quantity Changed Back To: " + singletonInstance.QuantityOriginal);
                    QuantityBoxLabel.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (singletonInstance.UpdatedSuccessfully == false)
                    {

                        // new quantity !=0
                        //Test on Product ID:519
                        // Chnange to dynamic via SlectionIndex or anything..

                        //DISABLE FOR TESTING:
                        //using (MFTDataContext MFTdb = new MFTDataContext(strConnectionString))
                        //{
                        //    var itemToChange = (from item in MFTdb.MFTCart
                        //                        where item.ProductID == singletonInstance.ItemToChange
                        //                        select item).Single();

                        //    itemToChange.ProductQuantity = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged;
                        //    itemToChange.ProductTotalPrice = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged * itemToChange.ProductPrice;
                        //    MFTdb.SubmitChanges();


                        //}
                        singletonInstance.SomethingChanged = false;
                        singletonInstance.UpdatedSuccessfully = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }

                    (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/Cart.xaml?refersh=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }


        }

        private void QuantityBoxLabel_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do same as QuantityBoxLabel_MouseLeave
            QuantityBoxLabel_MouseLeave(null, null);

        }

        private void QuantityBoxLabel_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
           //Cant be 0 . Already Filtered in ThirdPage

            if (QuantityBoxLabel.Text != "")
            {
                singletonInstance.QuantityOriginal = int.Parse(QuantityBoxLabel.Text);

            }
        }

        private void QuantityBoxLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
         //   TESTING;
           // this.QuantityBoxLabel.IsHitTestVisible = false;


            //Cant be 0 . Already Filtered in ThirdPage
            singletonInstance.QuantityOriginal = int.Parse(QuantityBoxLabel.Text);


        }

        private void QuantityBoxLabel_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QuantityBoxLabel.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, Quantity Textbox seems to be in CustomControl and tap on Quantity Textbox will only take you to Text_Changed. It should be in ListBox to get into Selection_Changed right? You have that CustomControl inside your ListBox?

Comment: I have Delete Button and Quantity Textbox inside  CustomControl. When I click on utton it first takes me to ListBox_SelectionChanged perfectly. But why doesn't clicking inside quantity textbox take me first to ListBox_SelectionChanged ?

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/kcbz11idj/image.png

Comment: You can add the number of quantities right? or your retrieving that values from your local storage?

Comment: Please check the Link is posted. Its my CutomControl being generated in listbox. Also, it shows quantity of choosen item in textbox. i want to change the quantity, and on MouseLeave, LostFocus method/eventhandler I have written the code to update quantity, but it requires the productid or listbox selected index so that it understands which item's quantity we are changing. just in delete button case, which goes to listbox_selectionchanged first, why doesnt clicking on textbox goto listbox_selectionchanged first. how will i forward selected index to update method now :(

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, We will get you the solution. If Quantity_TextChanged method is raised, just add these lines in your Quantity TextBox.

```
<TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

Now you will be redirected to listbox_SelectionChanged method. There, you will get the selected index of the listbox. Now raise the keyboard using,

```
QuantityTextBox.Focus();
```

Now again get the new value from the user, replace the old value with the new value using the selected index of the listbox and display the value again. Its simple right :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. <TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False" /> Works and on clicking on textbox, it goes first to listbox_SelectionChanged, but QuantityTextBox.Focus(); doesnt work. where to put QuantityTextBox.Focus();?

Comment: private void ListCart_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListCart.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                iList = ListCart.SelectedIndex;
                singletonInstance.ItemToChange = iList;
                ListCart.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }

            CustomCartFavControl cus = new CustomCartFavControl();
            cus.QuantityBoxLabel.Focus();
         }

Comment: Add QuantityBoxLabel.Focus() in LayoutUpdateEvent in Textbox. Like this, private void txtBox_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBox.Focus();
        }

Comment: No, This creates problem. My Page.xaml directly opens into CustomControl's QuantityBoxLabel_LostFocus() method and then QuantityBoxLabel_LayoutUpdated() method, resulting into a Blank page :(

Comment: I can't proceed further without seeing your code. Why are you using LostFocus()? These things might get collapsed.

Comment: On debugging i observed, it also is giving a continuous Loop between QuantityBoxLabel_MouseLeave and QuantityBoxLabel_LostFocus

Comment: CODE of Custom Control uploaded. please checkout

Comment: When a user changes the Quantity of item in Textbox, i have set the TextChanged Event to check whether the quantity is changed eg from 2 to 4 ..etc.. if quantity is changed then when keyboard gets close or user clicks outside textbox, means MouseLeave or LostFocus of this textbox, i want to update this new quantity to local store back and refresh the cart page again.

Comment: Why are you using both MouseLeave and LostFocus? I suggest you to use any one. And now what's your problem exactly?

Comment: Because after changing figure in Quantity Textbox, a user can either click anywhere on screen, or some users just press BACK key to close keyboard, so we need both methods.

Comment: Now exactly the problem was that Whenever i used to click on Quantity textbox, it just executed QuantityBoxLabel_MouseEnter without getting the SelectedIndex first, now you told me to do IsHitTestVisible="False" on this control. This solved phase one of problem but created another problem. On clicking on Quantity textbox now, we get the ListBox selectedindex but Quantity textbox is'nt enabled for changing value.

Comment: Ok, its simple. Add QuantityTextBox.IsHitTestVisible = True at the end of listBox_SelectionChanged and perform your action.

Comment: Did you notice, when i click in quantity textbox, though keyboard opens but  quantity textbox is readOnly

Comment: "Ok, its simple. Add QuantityTextBox.IsHitTestVisible = True at the end of listBox_SelectionChanged and perform your action. " tried already. not working: Am i doind it right? 
CustomCartFavControl cus = new CustomCartFavControl();
            cus.QuantityBoxLabel.IsHitTestVisible = true;

Comment: I cannot directly add QuantityTextBox.IsHitTestVisible = True in Page because QuantityTextBox doesnt directly exist in page, it exists in userCustomControl, so i tried to create instance of userCustomControl first.

Comment: private void ListCart_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListCart.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                iList = ListCart.SelectedIndex;
                singletonInstance.ItemToChange = iList;
                ListCart.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }

            CustomCartFavControl custom = new CustomCartFavControl();
            custom.QuantityBoxLabel.IsHitTestVisible = true;
         }

Comment: It gets DeadLoop, i mean, it loop endlessly into this method ListCart_SelectionChanged

Comment: Sorry @AtìfShabëër, It's little bit confusing and your code seems to be complex. You said, quantity textbox is readonly but later you said you want to change the value. I can suggest you another method, Just have list picker and add number of items you can get. Get the selected item(value) in listpicker in selection changed event and try to perform the task. I can able to solve the problem if I have source code but its not the proper way of getting your hard work. Just try as you can.

Comment: Can you get why its running endlessly? Because default value is -1 and in your if condition, you are assigning it again -1. The values gets changed here and again listcart_selectionChanged executes. Try setting some other value. If its -1, do return; else perform your task.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed the textbox and added ListPicker(Toolkit). It works  but one major problem is in the UPDATE QUEry, It says, An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: using (MFTDataContext MFTdb = new MFTDataContext(strConnectionString))
                {
                    var itemToChange = (from item in MFTdb.MFTCart
                                        where item.ProductID == singletonInstance.CartItemIDs[singletonInstance.ItemToChange]
                                        select item).Single();

                    itemToChange.ProductQuantity = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged;
                    itemToChange.ProductTotalPrice = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged * itemToChange.ProductPrice;
                    MFTdb.SubmitChanges();
  }

Comment: In which line you get InvalidOperationException?